# Sliding up footer

Tags: jquery, html, css, sticky-footer

I would like to make a sliding up footer on hover with a footer that stick at the bottom of the page.
I manage to stick my footer and make it behave like a button but it doesn't slide up on hover to show the  content of the footer.

here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='UTF-8'>
<title>sliding footer</title>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js'></script>

<style>
html, body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.slide { 
    border:1px solid black;
    width:100%; 
    height:150px; 
    display:none; 
    position:absolute;
    left: 0px;
    right:0px;
    bottom: 25px;   
}

.footer {
       position:absolute;
       bottom: 0px;
       height:25px;
       width: 100%;
       left: opx;
       right: 0px;
       border:1px solid black;
       display: inline-block;
       overflow: hidden;
       cursor:pointer;
           background:#FFE4E1;
    }
</style>
</head>


<body>              

<script type="text/javascript">

 $(".footer").hover(function () {
    $(this).children('.slide').slideToggle("fast");
  });

</script>

<div class="footer" > 
    Footer Button
   <div class="slide">

    <a href="#"> footer content 1</a>
    <a href="#"> footer content 2</a>
    <a href="#"> footer content 3</a>

   </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed up some of the css that I didn't need for [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aQmHB/) and made it look slightly different.

JS:

```
 $(".footer").hover(function () {
    $(".slide").slideToggle("fast");
  });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="footer" > 
    <div class="slide">
        <a href="#"> footer content 1</a>
        <a href="#"> footer content 2</a>
        <a href="#"> footer content 3</a>
    </div>
    Footer Button   
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.slide { 
    border:1px solid black;
    height:125px;    
    left: 0px;
    right:0px;
    bottom: 25px;
    display: none;    
    position: absolute;
}

.footer {
       position:absolute;
       bottom: 0px;
       height:25px;
       width: 100%;       
       left: opx;       
       right: 0px;
       border:1px solid black;
       display: inline-block;       
       cursor:pointer;
       background:#FFE4E1;       
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `animate` to get it working properly.

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.slide {
    border:1px solid black;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    position:absolute;
    left: 0px;
}
.footer {
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    height:20px;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    border:1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor:pointer;
    background:#FFE4E1;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(".footer").on({
    mouseover: function () {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            height : '40px'
        }, 1000);
        $('.slide').show();
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            bottom: "0px",
            height: '25px'
        }, 1000);
        $('.slide').hide();
    }
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/G2sqU/244/)**

Answer (score 0):

Just change a few things.

First of all, place your event listener in document ready:

```
$(function(){
$(".footer").hover(function () {
    $(this).children('.slide').slideToggle("fast");
});
});
```

Otherwise it won't do anything because you were calling it before that `.footer` was ever on the page. Second a few CSS things:

```
.slide {
    height:auto;
    .slide { 
    border:1px solid black;
    width:100%; 
    height:auto; /* was 150px. */
    display:none; 
    position:absolute;
    left: 0px;
    right:0px;
    bottom: 0px;   
}

.footer {
       position:absolute;
       bottom: 0px;
       height:25px;
       width: 100%;
       left: 0px; /* was opx. */
       right: 0px;
       border:1px solid black;
       display: inline-block;
       overflow: hidden;
       cursor:pointer;
       background:#FFE4E1;
}
```

This way it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I created a fiddle of a working version of your code, however instead of using slideToggle I used animate to animate the height of the footer and made it shrink when the user stops hovering on the div.

```
$(".footer").hover(function () {
    $(this).animate({height: 250});
}, function(){
    $(this).animate({height: 25});
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a88m6/)